# How to print out multi-line message from npm script

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to print out a multi-line message from an npm script?

My team has an alternative script that needs to run in place of `npm publish`.
So instead of running `npm publish` from the terminal, we should be running `npm run publish:lib`. But, some team members forget about the alternative script and end up just running `npm publish`.

**So what I've done so far is added this to my package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": "node -e \"console.log('Did you mean npm run publish:lib?')\"",
}
```

That way when they do run `npm publish`, they'll be reminded about the alternative script. However, I'm not satisfied with it because it's not very noticible, and also the words *console.log* get's printed out, which is kind of ugly.
[image]

My goal is to have something printed out that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using was the following:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "postpublish": "node publishWarning.js"
}
```

**publishWarning.js**

```
console.log('***************************************')
console.log('***************************************')
console.log('** Did you mean npm run publish:lib? **')
console.log('***************************************')
console.log('***************************************')
```